# Incorporate xsl code inside onclick of html element

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I have my code as follows `inside an XSLT File`:

```
<span onclick="window.location.href='<xsl:value-of select="/*/media/url"/>';">click here</span>
```

Also i tried this way:

```
<span onclick="window.location.href='{/*/media/url}';">click here</span>
```

Both break the xslt transformatioon. How do I incorporate the xsl code into this `span element onclick event`

Comment: This is extremely unclear. Is this in an XML file?  Is the XML file in which this line appears being transformed by an XSL engine? You haven't given us anywhere nearly enough context to understand the question.  What does _"break my page"_ mean?  You've been on SO long enough to know what's needed in a question.

Comment: @JimGarrison Updated question

Comment: OK, how is the XSLT applied?  We need much more context or the question is not answerable.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by applied? I have this code inside an XSLT File which gets instantiated by some backend php code. All I need to know is how to include the data into this javascript inside the onclick event applied to the html element (inline)

Comment: Your first attempt fails because tags cannot be nested. Your second attempt works and does not "*break the xslt transformatioon*". And it's better (simpler) than the answer you have accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this if it works:

```
<xsl:variable
    name="clickAction"
    select="concat('window.location.href=&quot;', /*/media/url, '&quot;')">
</xsl:variable>

<span onclick="{$clickAction}">click here</span>
```

OR

```
<span onclick="{concat('window.location.href=&quot;', /*/media/url, '&quot;')}">click here</span>
```

Comment: Can you explain it please

Comment: You cann't mix between string and expression, that's why your code didn't work.

Comment: The first suggestion does not work: the result is `<span onclick="$clickAction">click here</span>`

Comment: Thank @michael.hor257k, I updated the code. Should have curly braces.